# How script recognize this is the end of the line in file?

Tags: bash

how does the script know when is end of line :

```
 while read line;

 do for word in $line; do ?
```

Same question is for word, how script knows that need to read only one word per iteration ? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash shell treats '\n' [Enter Key] character as end of the input.
Each set of characters you typed till it reads space character will be treated as word. Its similar how we count the number of words in a sentence.

For more information check here http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0130.php[1](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0130.php)

Comment: do you know maybe how can I write this using script, i want to have file with few rows and 2 columns, in first column is written path to source file, in another column is written path to target file, and i just want to copy and replace source file instead of target f.?